# Reversed Pyramid Design in Perl

Tags: perl, reverse

I need to input a number of lines and a single character to use for the reverse pyramid.The output must look like the following:

```
Maximum number of characters in a line : 6
Enter Echo Character : $

$$$$$$
$$$$$
$$$$ 
$$$ 
$$
$
```

This is what I have so far:

```
print "Maximum number of characters in a line : ";
$size = <>;
print "Enter Echo Character : ";
$character = <>;
chomp($size);

Loop: for $row (1 .. $size)
{
    for $column (1 .. ($size+1))
    {
        if ($column < $row)
        {
            print "\n";
            next Loop;
        }
        print $character;
    }
}
```

But I am definitely doing something wrong because I cannot get the output I need after a couple hours of trying. I am new at Perl and any help I can get is definitely appreciated.

```
KMBP:Assignment 13 mypc$ perl pyramidtest.pl 
Maximum number of characters in a line : 6
Enter Echo Character : $
$
$
$
$
$
$
$





KMBP:Assignment 13 mypc$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you setting `$row` from `1 .. $size` if you want a *reverse* pyramid?

Why are you setting the end of the range for `$column` to `$size + 1` instead of `$row`?

Why do you have some kind of strange logic for determining when to print a newline?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Maximum number of characters in a line : ";
chomp(my $size = <>);

print "Enter Echo Character : ";
chomp(my $character = <>);

while ($size) {
    for (1 .. $size) {
        print $character;
    }

    print "\n";
    $size--;
}
```

Note: you probably want to validate that `$size` is a positive integer, or else you might get unexpected results for certain inputs!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I see what you're saying about the positive number check and will look around on how to add that.

Answer (score 2):

The `x` operator is also useful for this.

```
use feature qw(say);

print 'character? ';
chomp(my $char = <STDIN>);
print 'length? ';
chomp(my $length = <STDIN>);

while ($length) {
    say $char x $length;
    $length--;
}
```